# Is there any git "for humans"?

Tags: software-rec, version-control

A few non-technical friends have expressed interest in many of the cool abilities of `git` (the version control and rollbacks, not the offsite duplication), but definitely don't want to deal with `git-*` or even `git-cola` or any full featured GUI.

Does there yet exist a GUI frontend to git that non-technical users can use for versioning?  e.g. something that avoids conflicts at all costs instead of expecting the user to handle the fallout.  Eventually someone will make their millions this way (like all the automatic backup solutions that are secretly `rsync`), I'm just asking if it's been invented *yet*.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's called [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com).

The intersection of SCM and "humans" is really just a few things:

- easy, consistent replication ("checkout")
- easy, consistent publication ("checkin")
- past versions ("history")
- and a good pervasive UI that makes these things obvious

[image: screenshot of dropbox showing previous versions menu itme]

I claim Dropbox has all these, that's why it's so popular, and why they've [made millions](http://www.forbes.com/sites/victoriabarret/2012/11/13/dropbox-hits-100-million-users-says-drew-houston/).

Comment: good point.  They're aware of dropbox, it's more the ability to have a local executable that does the version control so they don't have to pay for space in the cloud, etc.  They're also turned on by quick branching and merging, but I contend this will never be available for humans.

Comment: You might find Cubby more appropriate then, with its peer to peer sync features.